# Difference between bucket() and get_bucket() on google storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I want to download the blobs on a google storage bucket. What is the difference between the `get_bucket` and the `bucket` methods a client has? Why do they differ in permissions? Can both be used to download blobs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a look to the code, you can see that

- bucket() is simply a declaration, without any request to Cloud Storage to check if the bucket exist or not (you find the same logic with blob() method)
- get_bucket() performs a call to Cloud Storage API to get the bucket with it's metadata (it's the same logic with get_blob())

In summary, with get_xxx you check the existence of the object, with the other method, you simply declare a name without checks.

With both, you can download the content of a Blob.